# API not working

Tags: python, windows, flask

I am new to python and trying to create a simple API. below is the code for the same.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000)
```

I have saved this as code as "hello-world.py".
When I am trying to run this file in command prompt using python command

```
python hello-world.py
```

[Command executed in command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdZPw.png)

Here I have no error but web page is not getting displayed. Below is the error on web page.

```
http://localhost:5000/
```

> This site can’t be reached
>   localhost refused to connect.
>   Search Google for localhost 5000
>   ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

*1st Issue - Even after running the code properly, why the web page is not displayed*

Now, I enter python command in my command prompt and then I try running file again `python hello-world.py`. Here I am getting the below error

```
>>>  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python hello-world.py
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

*2nd Issue - Why I am getting an error while trying run the hello-world.py*

Please guide me on how to resolve this issue.

Comment: OS-level firewall? And you are getting `SyntaxError` because you are not supposed to execute shell commands in the Python REPL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you're describing, I think you're trying to use the [Flask Quickstart](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/).  If so, have you done the following command in your command prompt enviroment?

`C:\path\to\app>set FLASK_APP=hello.py`

At which point if you run your code and it's correctly structured you should see

`Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/`

Because you don't see the "Running" on your prompt I would assume this hasn't been done.  If this doesn't work, I would just double check that Flask is installed and that Python sees it, and that you're following the steps in the tutorial correctly.

Edit: Also, I would recommend removing the hyphen in hello-world.py. It may help you avoid errors here and elsewhere in python coding. See the responses to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761519/is-it-ok-to-use-dashes-in-python-files-when-trying-to-import-them).

Comment: Thanks @DeepSpace for your time and effort to guide me to the resolution.

Comment: @Arjun k for your time and effort to guide me to the resolution

Answer (score 0):

1st issue - firewall or some other services may be blocking your port.

2nd Issue - you are running in interactive terminal. Please execute the command in command prompt.