# Why can't I import python-rosbag in Google Colab?

Tags: python, ros, google-colaboratory

I am attempting to use Google Colab to run https://github.com/ARiSE-Lab/deepTest deep neural network software developed on Ubuntu.
I was able to run the install.sh with small modifications.
I was successful, after adding "!", in loading:

! sudo apt-get install python-rosbag
   ! sudo apt-get install python-genmsg
   ! sudo apt-get install python-genpy
   ! sudo apt-get install python-rosgraph-msgs1
This installed many files including:

```
Setting up python-rosbag (1.13.5+ds1-3) ...
```

However, when I ran the program generate_hmb3.py whose 2nd line is:

```
import rosbag
```

I got an invalid syntax error message.  When I changed the line to read:

```
import python-rosbag
```

I got the message:

```
  File "<ipython-input-12-37a7e266f3af>", line 7
import python-rosbag
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any solutions to this problem?

Comment: Any suggestions @AntonMatosov? @Anton Matosov

Comment: Ideas @Lahiru Karunaratne?

Comment: Any ideas @fet.atas ?

Comment: Any ideas @Danf ?

Comment: If you want to know where your installation goes, just try e.g.: `find / -name "*rosbag*"`. However, it seems that you maybe install your ROS installation into some virtual env.? Just install ROS from the terminal like explained [here](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu), or into the environment where your python can find it

Comment: Any help @JeanNassar

Comment: `!python2.7 -c "import rosbag"` works, so I guess apt is installing using the wrong version of python. Maybe try this package from the answer from @simbamford https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59794328/importing-rosbag-in-python-3

Answer (score 0):

**Import issue**

Make sure you have your Python path set which should be done via the [source](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment#Managing_Your_Environment) command. You can easily check the correct path via

```
echo $PYTHONPATH
# which gives me
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

**Importing modules with dashes:**

Dashes are not allowed in python's import names ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/761531/2084944)). And there isn't any standard module called `python-rosbag`. As far as I know, there is only `rosbag`. If it is your own written module, you can do that using `__import__()`. For example:

```
foobar = __import__("foo-bar")
```

But you really should rename the module instead.

Comment: Thanks@Tik0.  I did the following:

Comment: Thanks@Tik0.  I did the following:  ! which python.    and got:  /usr/local/bin/python. Then I asked: ! python --version    Python 2.7.15+ .  Then I asked: !find / -name "*rosbag*". And I got a lot including: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosbag
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosbag/rosbag_main.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosbag/rosbag_main.pyc

Answer (score 0):

I tried a bunch of different things* and I think that this is an issue with ros still using python 2.7.

I actually couldn't get it to work as intended, but using https://github.com/event-driven-robotics/importRosbag worked for me.

* Like adding the paths from python2.7 and fiddling with importlib and imp. Couldn't get it to work; I get an error `AttributeError: module 'rospy' has no attribute 'names'`