# Error: Could not import "flask-app-hello"

Tags: python, flask

**When I run my flask app by following commands:**

```
$ export FLASK_APP=flask-app-hello.py
$ flask run
```

**I get this error:**

```
 * Serving Flask app "flask-app-hello.py"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

Error: Could not import "flask-app-hello".
```

Comment: You can't use hyphens in python module names - use underscores `flask_app_hello.py`

Comment: That's it. Rename the file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it ok to use dashes in Python files when trying to import them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761519/is-it-ok-to-use-dashes-in-python-files-when-trying-to-import-them)

Answer (score 4):

This error is shown because you are not into the folder that contains **flask-app-hello.py** type cd [foldername] in terminal to go into that folder. Then run Flask app.

Answer (score -1):

You can write this in the .env file:

```
$env:FLASk_APP='apps/minimalapp/app.py'

$env:FLASK_DEBUG=1
```

This is for window. Maybe you can [try it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HI5ms.png).