# Setuptools installing library instead of its packages

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

Here is my `tree` (simplified):

```
└── internal_models
    ├── models
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── api
    │       ├── my_code.py
    └── setup.py
```

And my `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='internal-models',
      version='0.0.2',
      description='models package',
      packages=["models"],
      zip_safe=False,
      install_requires=[])
```

When I install with `pip install .` or `python setup.py build`, Setuptools installs `internal-models` (which cannot be imported anyway because of an illegal character), instead of the package I want, `models`. What am I doing wrong? Have read the setuptools [Quickstart](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/quickstart.html) and various related questions but am still confused.

[Minimal reproducible example](https://github.com/lordgrenville/internal-models)

Comment: Try moving the setup.py file to the models file?

Comment: No, that didn't help

Comment: Can you please provide us a Github [mcve] repo to experiment?

Comment: @phd done. Changed setup.py to setup.cfg to simplify but otherwise identical. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I think `setup.cfg` still requires `setup.py`: `pip install .` ->
ERROR: Directory '.' is not installable. Neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.

Comment: It works for me with `git clone https://github.com/lordgrenville/internal-models.git; pip install -e internal_models/`. Will edit the repo to include a `setup.py` though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this problem was only due to my misunderstanding, but I thought I'd clarify it in an answer since there's a distinction here that wasn't so clear (to me) from the `Setuptools` documentation.

The **distribution name** defined in `setup.py`/`setup.cfg` is the overall package name, which will be saved in your environment's `site-packages` directory, and is output by `pip freeze`. It is not importable. Valid names are defined in PEP 508. They may, for example, contain a dash, which in import packages is, while not illegal, discouraged by PEP 8. (It [can't be imported in the standard way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761519/is-it-ok-to-use-dashes-in-python-files-when-trying-to-import-them), since Python interprets the dash as a minus sign.)

The **import packages** (or **modules**) defined in `setup.py`/`setup.cfg` are what you can import in Python. So in my case, `internals-models` was being installed, but the way I would use the `models` package is through `import models` (the behaviour I wanted).