# How can I import a python class which is in a sub directory, where the script and sub directory both have hyphens?

Tags: python-3.x, python-importlib

Given below is my folder structure.

```
Main_Folder
|
|-my_script.py
|
|-level-1
    |--__init__.py
    |
    |--level-2
        |--__init__.py
        |
        |--new_script.py
```

The new script is a small code snippet

```
class check:
    def print_me():
        print("inside the class")
```

I am trying to import this inside `my_script.py`.
The code snippet is:

```
import importlib

mod = importlib.import_module("level-1.level-2.new_script.check")

my_instance = check()

my_instance.print_me()
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/danish/tuts/del_check/my_script.py", line 4, in <module>
    mod = importlib.import_module("level-1.level-2.new_script.check")
  File "/home/danish/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 970, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'level-1.level-2.new_script.check'; 'level-1.level-2.new_script' is not a package
```

I went ahead and searched following [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761519/is-it-ok-to-use-dashes-in-python-files-when-trying-to-import-them) . But no use. What am I doing wrong here. **Also, changing the directory name is not an option**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first update your class method:

```
class check:
    def print_me(self):
        print("inside the class")
```

Then we can import the module. Note, `check` is a class so let's not try to import it as a module.

```
import importlib
mod = importlib.import_module("level-1.level-2.new_script")
my_instance = mod.check()
my_instance.print_me()
```

This should give you:

```
inside the class
```

Comment: Thank you . I forgot that self option in the class definition and forgot to call the method as an instance. Thank you.